# Using column names in IMPORTRANGE QUERY

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have used a script that allows me to substitute column names for Col# format in QUERY of a sheet in the same Google *workbook* but when I call the QUERY from a different Google Sheets spreadsheet with IMPORTRANGE, I get this error:

> Range not found (line 11, file "SQLfunction")

My calling cell looks like this:

```
=QUERY(
  IMPORTRANGE("long-hairy-key","MASTER!A:BN"),
  IMPORTRANGE("long-hairy-key",SQL("MASTER!A:BN",STATS!D33,true)),
  1
 )
```

STATS!D33 is this:

```
select TRACT,PARID,LINE,OWN1,T_STATUS,ExhibitDate,FEET2,NewEase,TWSacres,ExistEase,PrevDistTWS,ATWSacres,ARdistance,StagingArea,Damages,UpdateReason,ACQ_STATUS where Col51 <>'' ORDER BY LINE ASC, TRACT ASC Label OWN1 'Landowner'
```

and the SQL function is from [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/vTgy3hgj4M4).

Can someone recommend how I might adjust the script to accommodate IMPORTRANGE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The referred SQL() custom function is not able to access an external spreadsheet. You have to adapt the SQL() custom function to make it able to access an external spreadsheet or to redesign your formula.

If you go for redesigning the formula, one approach is to move the import of the external data out of the "main formula". To do this,

1. First, get the external range. Add a new sheet (assume that it's name is `Sheet1`) and add the following formula to A1 `=IMPORTRANGE("long-hairy-key","MASTER!A:BN")`
2. Second, replace the "main formula" by other like the next one:

```
=QUERY(
   Shee1!A:BN,
   SQL("Sheet1!A:BN",STATS!D33,true)),
   1
 )
```

Comment: Ruben, This looks like a reasonable way to do it, but won't timing be an issue?

Comment: @JimGarner: This answer has two parts. The main part is the first paragraph, the second part is about one of the two solution paths mentioned in the first part. I think that you should consider to update your question or to post a new one to include more details about the specific scenario and the timing related concerns.

Comment: I am going to mark this as the ANSWER because it looks to be the best approach for my needs. HOWEVER, Max Makhrov answer is likely better for others.
I do have a potential issue with Timing for the @Ruben answer that can only be resolved by testing.

Comment: After using this solution for several weeks, I can attest this is the best answer for me.

If you want to use the SQL Script so that you can use HEADER NAMES in place of Col1,Col2,Col34...  And you need to accomplish this in a different Google Sheet using IMPORTRANGE,

Use IMPORTRANGE to bring the needed sheet over, THEN
Use you QUERY and SQL function in the script to pull from that sheet.

HIDE the IMPORTRANGE sheet, leaving the downside... ALL data is being imported into that sheet where someone could see it... which was prolly the reason you made the different sheet in the 1st place!

Answer (score 0):

You may generate sql statement with formulas.

**Step1.** Use importrange to get headers only.

Paste this formula in Sheet1 A1:

```
=transpose(IMPORTRANGE("long-hairy-key","MASTER!A1:BN1"))
```

Need to transpose the data to make vertical list of field names.

**Step2.** Add column numbers.

Paste this formula in B1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(OFFSET(A1,,,counta(A:A))))
```

In this step you will get table, which looks like this:

```
  A               B
1 FieldName1      1
2 FieldName2      2
3 FieldName3      3
4 FieldName4      4
5 FieldName5      5
```

**Step3.** Combine the SQL statement.

Use column C to indicate, which columns are to be selected in your query:

```
  A               B    C
1 FieldName1      1    1
2 FieldName2      2
3 FieldName3      3    1
4 FieldName4      4
5 FieldName5      5    1
```

And use this formula in free cell (F1):

```
="select Col"&JOIN(", Col",FILTER(B:B,C:C=1))
```

In my case, this formula gives string `select Col1, Col3, Col5`, and this can be used in query formula:

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("long-hairy-key","MASTER!A:BN"), F1)
```

Use additional columns to make your SQL smarter, add `where` clause, `order by`, `label` and so on.

---

**Update**

So this step-by-step solution doesn't solve the problem with rearranged columns.

The trick is to use column names list and save it as values:

1. paste the formula from step1: `=transpose(IMPORTRANGE("long-hairy-key","MASTER!A1:BN1"))`
2. copy it → go to paste spacial → values

Then you need to go through steps 1 and 2 in order to make the list of current firld numbers.

And then you'll have actually two tables. The first one will hold actual field list and field numbers, generated by formulas from step1 and step2. Here's `Table1`:

```
  A               B
1 FieldName1      1
2 FieldName2      2
3 FieldName3      3
4 FieldName4      4
5 FieldName5      5
```

And the second table will have SQL settings. Here's `Table2`::

```
  A               B    C
1 FieldName1      1    1
2 FieldName3      3
3 FieldName2      2    1
4 FieldName4      4
5 FieldName5      5    1
```

Field names in it must be entered as values. Column B will contain `vlookup` function:

```
= vlookup(A1, table1!A:B, 2, 0)
```

or even `ArrayFormula`:

```
= arrayformula(vlookup(offset(A1,,,counta(A1:A)), table1!A:B, 2, 0))
```

That's all you need to start. Then just make your query smarter.

Comment: Great Max. It really did answer the question directly and it is good logic. But the reason to want to use field names rather than Col numbers is when Columns are rearranged or inserted.

So this solution won't overcome that because I think you would have to go back through and re-set column C for those fields that have changed. Right?

Comment: That's right! To avoid the problem with rearranged columns, use unique list of fields and save it as values. Then query would work fine if only field names won't change. I'll update my answer to show how.

Comment: while this approach would work for me to use column names, it would have more overhead management for fieldname changes, column changes, and insertions.
So, although this is a solution, the better approach for me is as @Ruben has offered; to first move the data over in an importrange, where I can hide the TAB and then use the existing SQL script which I like so far, to run on the now local Tab/Sheet in the same book. Thank you Max.

Comment: Thanx Max. Wish I had your brain for this.
The columns will re-arrange. Header Column Names will change, and multiple SQL Queries are done on my MASTER data.

To use your solution would require managing many new columns that would refer to WHICH SQL would be created, whereas starting each SQL-QUERY call with the names for the columns and knowing that would update even if things changed, is the better solution. 

I don't want to discourage others from using your solution, as it is a good approach. Unfortunately my scenario makes it unwieldy due to the known many changes that will happen.